# Is the following inequality true : $(||f(|A|)||)(||g(|A^*|)||) \geq ||A||$?

Tags: operator-theory

Please help me on this.

Give an example of an operator $A\in B(H)$, such that 
$$(||f(|A|)||)(||g(|A^*|)||) < ||A||$$ 
where $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative continuous functions  on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying  $$f(t )g(t)=t , t\in [0,\infty)$$

Or is    the   following   inequality  true :
$$(||f(|A|)||)(||g(|A^*|)||) \geq ||A||$$ 
where $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative continuous functions  on $[0,\infty)$ satisfying  $$f(t )g(t)=t , t\in [0,\infty)$$ & $A\in B(H)$.

I have no idea how to finish it. Can anyone enlighten me the way of solution please?

Comment: please help me to solve it. i really have no idea how to approach it

Comment: Have you considered the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?